# Unexpected results when using @extend for themes

Tags: sass

I'm refactoring some of my Sass code and I came across a weird issue. My code currently looks like this:

```
// household
$household_Sector: 'household';
$household_BaseColor: #ffc933;

// sports
$sports_Sector: 'sports';
$sports_BaseColor: #f7633e;


// the mixin to output all sector specific css
@mixin sector-css($sector_Sector,$sector_BaseColor) {

    .sector-#{$sector_Sector} {
        &%baseColor {
            background-color: $sector_BaseColor;
        }
    }

}

// execute the mixin for all sectors
@include sector-css($household_Sector, $household_BaseColor);
@include sector-css($sports_Sector, $sports_BaseColor);


.product-paging {
    h2 {
        @extend %baseColor;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9092293)

The compiled result looks like this:

```
.product-paging h2.sector-household {
  background-color: #ffc933;
}

.product-paging h2.sector-sports {
  background-color: #f7633e;
}
```

But what I need is this:

```
.sector-household.product-paging h2 {
  background-color: #ffc933;
}

.sector-sports.product-paging h2 {
  background-color: #f7633e;
}
```

What I don't understand is why my placeholder (`&%baseColor`) isn't attached to the parent selector (`&%baseColor`) as I added the ampersand right in front of it?
Is this maybe a bug when combining `&` and `%`? Is there another solution on how to achieve what I want?

**EDIT**

Alright I figured out [why](http://thesassway.com/beginner/the-inception-rule) this isn't possible. Anyway is there a workaround for what I'd like to achieve?

Comment: Are you married to the idea of using extends for this purpose?

Comment: @cimmanon I previously had all sector color specific css inside the sector-css mixin and all the other stuff (margin, padding etc.) for these selectors in other files. I'd like to access the right color from these files now so that the selectors are only listed at one place... Hope you understand what I mean. I'm open for other solutions than extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extends, as you've already discovered, can get rather messy.  I would go about solving your problem by using an `@content` aware mixin in combination with global variables (this uses mappings, which are part of 3.3... you can do it with lists of lists, but it's a little less elegant):

```
$base-color: null; // don't touch
$accent-color: null; // don't touch

$sections:
    ( household:
        ( base-color: #ffc933
        , accent-color: white
        )
    , sports:
        ( base-color: #f7633e
        , accent-color: white
        )
    );


// the mixin to output all sector specific css
@mixin sector-css() {
    @each $sector, $colors in $sections {
        $base-color: map-get($colors, base-color) !global;
        $accent-color: map-get($colors, accent-color) !global;
        &.sector-#{$sector} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

.product-paging {
    @include sector-css() {
        h2 {
            background-color: $base-color;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.product-paging.sector-household h2 {
  background-color: #ffc933;
}

.product-paging.sector-sports h2 {
  background-color: #f7633e;
}
```

**Update**:  Since you want to guarantee that the sector class is always at the top, you just need to switch around a little.

```
@mixin sector-css() {
    @each $sector, $colors in $sections {
        $base-color: map-get($colors, base-color) !global;
        $accent-color: map-get($colors, accent-color) !global;
        .sector-#{$sector} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

@include sector-css() {
    &.product-paging {
        h2 {
            background-color: $base-color;
        }

        h3 {
            background-color: #CCC;
        }

        h2, h3 {
            color: $accent-color;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great approach! Unfortunately it doesn't fit my needs completely as I've further nested selectors: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9094908
Any idea how to solve that? The sector class should always be on the parent. And is there a chance to merge selectors with same properties without extend? http://sassmeister.com/gist/9094944

Comment: You just need to switch your selectors around a little bit, but it's still the same concept.  Added an example for your 2nd example.

Comment: One further question. It's not working on my local machine. I've updated Sass to version 3.3.0.alpha but I always get a syntax error `"Syntax error: Invalid CSS after " ( household": expected ")", was ":"A on line 7` Any quick hint what I maybe missed?

Comment: Sounds like a version issue.  If you're running the watch command from a different console than where you updated the gem from, it can cause you to still be running off of the old gem.  I'm afraid I can't help any further in this regard.