# Simplify SCSS mixin on class

Tags: html, css, sass, mixins

I'm looking for a simpler/better way for changing some colors when a certain class is applied to the body tag.

I hope you know what i mean...

Markup:

```
<body class="b1">
  CONTENT
</body>

<body class="b2">
  CONTENT
</body>
```

SCSS:

```
// colors
$b1: #505a73;
$b2: #aa3333;
$b3: #484733;

body.b1 {background: $b1;
  #div1 {border: 10px solid $b1;} 
  .class1 .label{color: $b1;}
  #nav li a{color:$b1;border: 4px solid $b1;}
  #nav2 li a{color:$b1;}
  #div2 .label {color:$b1;}
}

body.b2 {background: $b2;
  #div1 {border: 10px solid $b2;}
  .class1 .label{color: $b2;}
  #nav li a{color:$b2;border: 4px solid $b2;}
  #nav2 li a{color:$b2;}
  #div2 .label {color:$b2;}
}

body.b3 {background: $b3;
  #div1 {border: 10px solid $b3;}
  .class1 .label{color: $b3;}
  #nav li a{color:$b3;border: 4px solid $b3;}
  #nav2 li a{color:$b3;}
  #div2 .label {color:$b3;}
}
```

Comment: So you're theming?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882528/unexpected-results-when-using-extend-for-themes or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552529/dynamic-sass-variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lamotta solution may be slightly better semantically. However maybe a less complex solution would be just to use a mixin.

```
$b1: #505a73;
$b2: #aa3333;
$b3: #484733;

@mixin change-colour($class, $colour) {
    &.#{$class}{
        background: $colour;
        #div1 {
            border: 10px solid $colour;
        }
        .class1 .label{
            color: $colour;
        }
        #nav li a{
            color:$colour;
            border: 4px solid $colour;
        }
        #nav2 li a{
            color:$colour;
        }
        #div2 .label {
            color:$colour;
        }
    }
}

body {
    @include change-colour(b1, $b1);
    @include change-colour(b2, $b2);
    @include change-colour(b3, $b3);
}
```

Also, I have spread the code out a little but by writing your code like that its much easier to read. You can get SASS to compile a minified version anyway so I like to have my `scss` files as readable as possible for other developers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cimmanon! This trick did the job:

```
$base-color: null; // don't touch

$sections:
    ( 
      1:( base-color: #505a73),
      2:( base-color: #aa3333),
      3:( base-color: #484733),
      4:( base-color: #878f7a),
      5:( base-color: #3a3e47),
      6:( base-color: #887766),
      7:( base-color: #447755),
    );

@mixin sector-css() {
    @each $sector, $colors in $sections {
        $base-color: map-get($colors, base-color) !global;
        body.b#{$sector} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

@include sector-css() {
  & {background: $base-color;
    #div1 {border: 10px solid $base-color;} 
    .class1 .label{color: $base-color;}
    #nav li a{color:$base-color;border: 4px solid $base-color;}
    #nav2 li a{color:$base-color;}
    #div2 .label {color:$base-color;}
  }
}
```